# Fourier series and zeta function

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Does anybody know what function this Fourier series comes from? $\sum_{q=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(2\pi q x)}{q^{1+\alpha}}$ Seems like a $\zeta(1+\alpha)$ but with cosines on top... is there any connection? The parameter is $0<\alpha<1$. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure if there is a proper rigorous process by which one can recover a function from its Fourier (cosine) series. Looking at the [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+of+f%28x%29+%3D+%5Csum_%7Bq%3D1%7D%5E10+%5Cfrac%7B%5Ccos%282%5Cpi+q+x%29%7D%7Bq%5E%7B1%2Bpi%2F4%7D%7D) of a partial sum in Wolfram suggests this is an even extension of a parabola of some sort, but this is strictly a guess.

Comment: I don't know about the Fourier series part, but the expression itself can be written as $$\tfrac{1}{2} \big(\text{Li}_{\alpha +1}(e^{-2 i \pi  x})+\text{Li}_{\alpha
   +1}(e^{2 i \pi  x})\big)$$ where Li is the [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: I agree it is even since it has inly cosines, but I doubt it is simply a quadratic as the denominators I’d expect then would be something like $n^2$...

Comment: Looking into polylogarithm function I see a link to so called Clausen functions whose real part seems  ti have Fourier series equal to this one. I guess there might not be an elementary function corresponding to the series given after all...